# Relation between positive elements of a $C^{\star}$ algebra and positive elements of its unitization

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

> Is there any relation between positive elements of a $C^{\star}-$ algebra $A$ and positive elements of unitization of $A$?

I have recently learned about positive elements so can’t see it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of the unitization are $(a,\lambda)$ with $a\in A$, $\lambda\in\mathbb C$.

One characterization of positive elements is that they are always of the form $c^*c$. So, if $c^*c\in A$ is positive, then 
$$
(c^*c,0)=(c,0)^*(c,0)
$$
is also positive in the unitization.

There are lots of "new" positive elements in the unitization, though. For starters, all $(0,\lambda)$ with $\lambda\geq0$. Positive elements are selfadjoint, so if $(a,\lambda)\geq0$ then $a=a^*$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb R$. You have 
$$
(a,\lambda)=(a,0)+(0,\lambda)=(a,0)+\lambda I. 
$$
So 
$$
\sigma((a,\lambda))=\sigma((a,0)+\lambda I)=\sigma((a,0))+\lambda. 
$$
Thus $(a,\lambda)$ will be positive precisely when $\sigma(a)\subset[-\lambda,\infty)$.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.